# Microsoft Remote Assistance

Tags: remote-desktop

Is it possible to use Microsoft Remote assistance with out the intervention of the end user?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "intervention". You mean the end user not noticing? Or not being able to stop it? Or not being able to use mouse and keyboard whilst the remote party is logged in?

Comment: By "end user" do you mean the "helper" or the "helped"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not what it's intended to be used for - it was written so you can easily help your friends/relatives/etc. while they're sitting at their PCs.

If you want to do normal remote access stuff, look into Remote Desktop or 3rd party applications such as VNC.

Comment: It is also for use as a helpdesk type tool - indeed we use Windows Remote Assistance instead of paying through the roof for other products that don't bring a great deal more functionality.

Comment: @Ben - good call. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly.

The remote assistance client has an option to request the end user (if you know the IP address or computer name) to allow you to view their screen, then another to allow you to take control.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you're looking to achieve from SCCM remote control if you have it available